# Using Row_Number to deal with non unique data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 4 columns a,b,c,d.
Some of my rows have the same values for all columns, is there any option to use row_number to insert same row number for those rows and continue counting if at least one of the values is different from values in the previous row

Example:

```
a b c d
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 3
1 1 1 3
1 1 2 4
```

I need it to look like: r=row_number

```
r a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 2
3 1 1 1 3
3 1 1 1 3
4 1 1 2 4
```

P.S. How to write here something like a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @t table(a int, b int, c int, d int)
insert @t values(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,2),
      (1,1,1,2),(1,1,1,3),(1,1,1,3),(1,1,1,4)    
select dense_rank() over(order by a,b,c,d) r, a,b,c,d from @t
```

Result:

```
r   a   b   c   d
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   2
2   1   1   1   2
3   1   1   1   3
3   1   1   1   3
4   1   1   1   4
```

Comment: @MichaelCherevko no problem. If you edit your code, you can see how I modified your code to be more readable. Making it easier for you next time